# Верстка меню

Tags: вёрстка, css

Всем привет! Подскажите как сверстать вот такое меню
[image]

Проблема в том, что я не могу разобраться с точками...Ширина пунктов всегда разная, а точки должны подстраиваться, что бы не добавлять их постоянно руками. Можно как-то реализовать такое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Держите [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/DnL5T/1/). Если не беспокоит, что в осле седьмой и ниже версии работать не будет, то должно чем-то помочь.

Answer (score 2):

Можно, например [так](http://www.search-this.com/2007/11/26/css-a-recipe-for-success/), однако может возникнуть проблема из-за фона, у вас же градиент, да?

Comment: в этом-то и проблема, что там с фоном не сделать...